# How to validate payload with microrouter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, microservices

I am using this code and created  a microservice

```
const { json, send } = require('micro')
const { router, post } = require('microrouter')
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY)
console.log(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY)
module.exports = router(
    post('/', async (req, res) => {
        const data = await json(req)
        try {
            const { status } = await stripe.charges.create(data)
            send(res, 200, { status })
        } catch (err) {
            send(res, 500, { message: err.message })
        }
    })
)
```

I can make a `post` request here using `microrouter` but how can I validate the payload body to get only the required fields only.

Please help if someone know any module to validate microservice post payload.

Answer (score 1):

You can use joi npm and express validator

```
const Joi = require("joi");
const validate = require("express-validation");

const validationSchema = {
      body: {
        Id: Joi.string()
          .guid()
          .required(), // mandatory
        FirstName: Joi.string().required(), // mandatory
        LastName: Joi.string().required(), // mandatory
        Email: Joi.string()
          .email({ minDomainAtoms: 2 })
          .required(), // mandatory
        Password: Joi.string().required(), // mandatory
        createdOn: Joi.date()
          .timestamp()
          .required(), // mandatory

      }
    };
```

Router File

```
module.exports = router(
    post('/',validate(validationSchema), async (req, res) => {
        const data = await json(req)
        try {
            const { status } = await stripe.charges.create(data)
            send(res, 200, { status })
        } catch (err) {
            send(res, 500, { message: err.message })
        }
    })
)
```

Comment: it should not throw a next error..similar example is given here https://scotch.io/tutorials/node-api-schema-validation-with-joi

Answer (score 0):

you have so common issue, as i can understand you can use for this payloads https://validatejs.org/#validators

this is email validate example:

```
var constraints = {
  from: {
    email: true
  }
};

validate({from: null}, constraints);
// => undefined

validate({from: ""}, constraints);
// => {"email": ["From is not a valid email"]}

validate({from: "nicklas@ansman"}, constraints);
// => {"email": ["From is not a valid email"]}

// Any TLD is allowed
validate({from: "nicklas@foo.faketld"}, constraints);
// => undefined

// Upper cased emails are allowed
validate({from: "NICKLAS@ANSMAN.SE"}, constraints);
// => undefined

constraints = {
  from: {
    email: {
      message: "doesn't look like a valid email"
    }
  }
};

validate({from: "foobar"}, constraints);
// => {"email": ["From doesn't look like a valid email"]}

// It allows unicode
validate({from: "first.läst@example.com"}, constraints);
// => undefined
```